# When is the sum of E[x] equal to E[sum(x)]?

Tags: probability, expected-value

This equivalence was used in my statistics course to prove that the sample mean is an unbiased estimator when the sample has:

1. a mean "mu"
2. a variance "sigma^2"

[Proof in my book](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N6tA3.jpg)

On Wikipedia I found that this equality doesn't always hold true:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value

(Under Uses and appliances it says that: https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/media/math/render/svg/b866cf6a1cae9adf1d0fee60b0c0fe0633c6b9f1)

Is there a general rule for when E[g(x)] = g(E[x]) ?

Comment: Notice that later on in the same section ("uses and applications"), the article goes on to say that$$E\left[\sum_{n=1}^\infty X_n\right]=\sum_{n=1}^\infty E[X_n]$$ *under certain conditions*. That is to say, expectation generally doesn't distribute over an infinite sum.

Comment: $E[g(x)] = g(E[x])$ is true in general when the expectations exist and $g(x)=ax+b$ for constants $a$ and $b$.  But this is not really related to the rest of your question

Comment: $\sum\limits_{n=1}^m E[X_n]$ is equal to $E\left[\sum\limits_{n=1}^m \right]$ when the expectations exist and the sum is over a finite number of terms